# How to add legend with labels of IDs to my code

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, cluster-analysis, legend

I have the electricity consumption of 25 houses, and I`m doing K-Means clustering on the dataset that holds those houses. After importing the dataset, pre-processing it, and applying K-Means with K=2, I plotted the data but when I`m adding the legend I`m getting this:

No handles with labels found to put in legend.

No error in the code and it is running but I want my code to generate automatic legends that hold the ID of each house starting from 0 to 24.

Here is my code where I`m plotting the data:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(13,13))
import itertools 
marker = itertools.cycle(('+', 'o', '*' , 'X', 's','8','>','1','<')) 
for cluster_index in [0,1]:
    plt.subplot(2,1,cluster_index + 1)
    
    for index, row in data1.iterrows():
        if row.iloc[-1] == cluster_index:
            plt.plot(row.iloc[1:-1] ,marker = next(marker) , alpha=1)
        
        plt.legend(loc="right")
       
        
    plt.plot(kmeans.cluster_centers_[cluster_index], color='k' ,marker='o', alpha=1)
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.tick_params(axis = 'x', which = 'major', labelsize = 10)  
    plt.xticks(rotation="vertical")
    plt.ylabel('Monthly Mean Consumption 2018-2019', fontsize=10)
    plt.title(f'Cluster {cluster_index}', fontsize=15)
    
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

I just want to have the legend in the output figure with the id of each house, please any help

Comment: You don't provide labels in [`plt.plot()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html) and plot the legend for every row.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I just don`t know how to add labels in which each house will have an ID to know from the plot the consumption of each house

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I do not have your data, I can not test it in a plot right now, but I assume the problem comes from not passing a `label` argument to `plt.plot` i.e.:

```
for index, row in data1.iterrows():
    if row.iloc[-1] == cluster_index:
        plt.plot(row.iloc[1:-1] ,marker = next(marker), alpha=1, label=index)
    
    plt.legend(loc="right")
```

Comment: Hi @AghyadSkaif, glad to hear that! You can accept the answer if it fully answered your question, it notifies everyone that the problem was solved :)

Comment: I just did, sorry I`m new here and I don`t know all the steps I should do